# How do I get TimeRanges from the youtube iframe player?

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

Is there a way to get the TimeRanges(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TimeRanges) from the video element inside the YouTube embed iframe? I can get it by using selectors (`document.querySelector(selectorOfTheVideoElement).played`) in console but I can't do it in my source code as I get cross-origin error despite having added the origin option in my youtube embed code.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow :). Can you describe your problem in a more detailed way, please? can you use jsfiddle and create a working example?

Comment: My problem is I want to get the viewer's viewing time and which part of the video has been watched or not and to do that, I decided to rely on the `played` attribute of the html5 video tag. However, for iframe embedded players such as YouTube, I can't directly target the video tag and I can't see anything about it in their docs. Here is a link to my sample embedded youtube video: https://jsfiddle.net/ted123/kuzfagLh/26/ no js code manipulation yet as I don't know how to target the video tag inside the youtube iframe